# Vert whitespace in tabular

Tags: tables

How do i create some vert whitespace above and below text in the tabular below?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\hline Navn & Notation & Betydning & Værdier & Tæthed $f(x)$ & Fordeling $F(x)$ & E[X] & V[X] \\
\hline Ligefordeling (Uniform) & Unif(a,b) & \pbox{4cm}{Måler udfald med lige sandsynlighed} & $ a \leq x \leq b$  & $\frac{1}{b-a+1}$ & $\begin{cases}
0, \ \ x<a\\
\frac{x-a+1}{b-a}, \ \  a \geq x \geq b\\
1, \ \ x>b
\end{cases}$ & $\frac{b+a}{2}$ & $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$  \\ 
\hline Bernoulli & Bern(p) & \pbox{4cm}{To punkts fordeling. Binomial n=1} & $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace $ & $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ & $(1-p)^{1-x}$  & $p$  & $p(1-p)$ \\ 
\hline Binomial & Bin(n,p) & \pbox{4cm}{Måler succeser i $n$ uafh. forsøg med konstant sandsynlighed} & $x=0,1,2,...,n$ & $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ & $\sum_{i=0}^{x} \begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$  & $np$ & $np(1-p)$ \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've tried using arraystretch, and other commands, but they only seem to stretch my cases enviroments.

Hope you can help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your table is too wide for usual paper sizes. You should consider reducing the font size and the value of `\tabcolsep` ort swapping rows and columns.

Comment: @Bernard - The OP uses the `landscape` document class option and loads the `savetrees` package with the option `extreme`, which makes for narrow page margins. Thus, there's actually more than enough space for the table on a (sideways) sheet of paper. :-)

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to check the expressions for the probability density function, the distribution function, and the variance of the uniform distribution.

Comment: besides i have to the middle inequalities on the cdf (Fordeling F(X)), what seems to be wrong? it shoudl be noted that this is for the discrete version of the uniform distribution. Making a another note now with the continous distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you load the booktabs package, replace the first instance of `\hline` with `\toprule`, and replace the remaining three instances of `\hline` with `\midrule`.

A full MWE, which uses a `tabularx` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llYccccc}
\toprule 
Navn & Notation & Betydning & Værdier & Tæthed $f(x)$ & Fordeling $F(x)$ & E[$X$] & V[$X$] \\
\midrule 
Ligefordeling (Uniform) & Unif($a,b$) & Måler udfald med lige sandsynlighed & $ a \leq x \leq b$  & $\frac{1}{b-a+1}$ & $\begin{cases}
0, \ \ x<a\\
\frac{x-a+1}{b-a}, \ \  a \geq x \geq b\\
1, \ \ x>b
\end{cases}$ & $\frac{b+a}{2}$ & $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$  \\ 
\midrule 
Bernoulli & Bern($p$) & To punkts fordeling.\ Binomial $n=1$ & $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace $ & $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ & $(1-p)^{1-x}$  & $p$  & $p(1-p)$ \\ 
\midrule 
Binomial & Bin($n,p$) & Måler succeser i $n$ uafh.\ forsøg med konstant sandsynlighed & $x=0,1,2,\dots,n$ & $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ & $\sum_{i=0}^{x} \begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$  & $np$ & $np(1-p)$ \\ 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a bunch! i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is to use the `stackengine` package to add `\addstackgap{}` around the most cramped item on each line.  This adds a 3pt buffer above/below the item.  An optional argument can be specified to change the size of the space buffer that is added.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[extreme]{savetrees}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\hline \addstackgap{Navn} & Notation & Betydning & Værdier & Tæthed $f(x)$ & Fordeling $F(x)$ & E[X] & V[X] \\
\hline Ligefordeling (Uniform) & Unif(a,b) & \pbox{4cm}{Måler udfald med lige sandsynlighed} & $ a \leq x \leq b$  & $\frac{1}{b-a+1}$ & \addstackgap{$\begin{cases}
0, \ \ x<a\\
\frac{x-a+1}{b-a}, \ \  a \geq x \geq b\\
1, \ \ x>b
\end{cases}$} & $\frac{b+a}{2}$ & $\frac{(b-a+1)^2-1}{12}$  \\ 
\hline Bernoulli & Bern(p) & \addstackgap{\pbox{4cm}{To punkts fordeling. Binomial n=1}} & $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace $ & $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ & $(1-p)^{1-x}$  & $p$  & $p(1-p)$ \\ 
\hline Binomial & Bin(n,p) & \addstackgap{\pbox{4cm}{Måler succeser i $n$ uafh. forsøg med konstant sandsynlighed}} & $x=0,1,2,...,n$ & $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ & $\sum_{i=0}^{x} \begin{pmatrix} n \\ x \end{pmatrix} p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$  & $np$ & $np(1-p)$ \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help. I appreciate it.